# Google Apps Script: Capture timestamp/email of logged in user who has updated a field in a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google Sheet that is shared with multiple people within my organization.  It will not be shared with anyone outside the company.  On said spreadsheet, when a user checks the box in column 1, I would like to put a timestamp in column 2, and the logged in user's email in column 3.

The timestamp works; and the email works when I do it; but it only works for me.  I have tried, deploying as a webapp (executing as the user accessing the app), deploying as a API Executable, all to no avail.

I suspect it's due to trying to trigger this from onEdit, since they may think I'm trying to harvest something that the user isn't releasing to me intentionally.  Since we're all in the same company, and it's not ill intended; I'm thinking there must be a solution.  A function which stores the logged in user, and another function that gets this value onEdit?

in the code I've pasted, I have it checking for values greater than 5, as I was unclear how to check for checkbox=TRUE.

Any advice?

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log(email);

 var r = s.getActiveCell();
 if( r.getColumn() == 1) { 

if(r.getValue()>5){  
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
var emailCell = r.offset(0, 3);
emailCell.setValue(email);}}
}
```

I expect any user within my organization, to check the box in column 1, and the time they checked it appears in column 2; and their email address shows up in column 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [installable onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers).